# InputMismatchException with Scanner when reading double from string with \n—Java

Tags: java, string, csv, java.util.scanner, inputmismatchexception

I am trying to read from a CSV file using the Scanner but I am getting an InputMismatchException when I try and read the last double and are there is more than one line in my CSV file. I think this is because it is reading \n as part of the double. How do I get it to ignore the line break?

**CSV file**

```
P1,25,30
P2,10,10
```

**Java**

```
public static ArrayList<MarkEntry> readCSV(File file) {
    ArrayList<MarkEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    try
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter(",");
        while (in.hasNext())
        {
            String title = in.next();
            double mark = in.nextDouble();
            double outOf = in.nextDouble(); //Program Crashes here
            entries.add(new MarkEntry(title, mark, outOf));
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("File: " + file + " not found");
    }

    return entries;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple delimeters:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter(",|\\r\\n");
```

Note: On Linux, the line ending is just `\n`, so you would use this code:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter(",|\\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the fact that your scanner tries to read up to the next delimiter (`,`) or to the end of the string. The last token will include the newline, and converting that value to a double results in the error you see.

[Trim](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--) the newline off before parsing with your scanner:

```
String input = "foo,bar,2.5\n";
Scanner in = new Scanner(input.trim()).useDelimiter(",");
System.out.println(in.next());
System.out.println(in.next());
System.out.println(in.nextDouble());
```